# Keras - Variational Autoencoder Incompatible shape

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to adapt [the code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/variational_autoencoder_deconv.py) to achieve 1-D convolution using 1-D input. The model is compilable so you can see the layers and shapes in `.summary()`, but it throws the error when `.fit()` the model. it seems to occur in loss computation. Below is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Lambda, Flatten, Reshape
from keras.layers import Conv1D, UpSampling1D
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K
from keras import metrics

num_conv = 6
batch_size = 100
latent_dim = 2
intermediate_dim = 128
epochs = 50
epsilon_std = 1.0

x = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, 310, 1)) 
conv_1 = Conv1D(1, kernel_size=num_conv,
                padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
conv_2 = Conv1D(64, kernel_size=num_conv,
                padding='same', strides=2, activation='relu')(conv_1)
conv_3 = Conv1D(64, kernel_size=num_conv,
                padding='same', activation='relu')(conv_2)

flatten = Flatten()(conv_3)
hidden = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')(flatten)

z_mean = Dense(latent_dim)(hidden)
z_log_var = Dense(latent_dim)(hidden)

def sampling(args):
    z_mean, z_log_var = args
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(batch_size, latent_dim), 
                              mean=0., stddev=epsilon_std)
    return(z_mean + K.exp(z_log_var/2) * epsilon)

z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dim,))([z_mean, z_log_var])

decoder_h = Dense(256, activation='relu')(z)
decoder = Dense(155, activation='relu')(decoder_h)
decoder = Reshape((155, 1))(decoder)
de_conv_1 = Conv1D(64, kernel_size=num_conv, 
                   padding='same', activation='relu')(decoder)
de_conv_2 = Conv1D(64, kernel_size=num_conv,
                   padding='same', activation='relu')(de_conv_1)
upsamp = UpSampling1D(2)(de_conv_2)
x_decoded_mean = Conv1D(1, kernel_size=num_conv,
                        padding='same', activation='relu')(upsamp)
x_decoded_mean = Reshape([310, 1])(x_decoded_mean)

def vae_loss(x, x_decoded_mean):
    x_ = x[:, 150:160, :]
    x_decoded_mean_ = x_decoded_mean[:, 150:160, :]
    xent_loss = 10 * metrics.mean_squared_error(x_, x_decoded_mean_)
    kl_loss = - 0.5 * K.sum(1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) -K.exp(z_log_var), axis=-1)
    return(xent_loss + kl_loss)

vae = Model(x, x_decoded_mean)
vae.summary()
vae.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss=vae_loss)
```

The input data shape is (n_sample, 310, 1).
It is an one-D time-series but I include prior and posterior 150 frames
to predict the middle 10 frames, resulting in 310 frames as input.

In `vae_loss()`, the reason that `x` and `x_decoded_mean` are sliced is that the purpose is to reconstruct the middle 10 frames with additional information of prior and posterior 150 frames. Therefore I want to force the model to focus on loss computed only from the middle 10 frames.

I got the following error when I `.fit()` the model:

```
# X.shape == (n_samples, 310, 1)
# n_samples % batch_size == 0

vae.fit(x=X, y=X, batch_size=batch_size,
        epochs=epochs,
        shuffle=True)
```

The long error below:

```
Epoch 1/50
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/yjluo/WORK/pitchPerfect/vae/model2.py in <module>()
     77 vae.fit(x=X, y=X, batch_size=batch_size,
     78         epochs=epochs,
---> 79         shuffle=True)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.pyc in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, **kwargs)
   1496                               val_f=val_f, val_ins=val_ins, shuffle=shuffle,
   1497                               callback_metrics=callback_metrics,
-> 1498                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1499
   1500     def evaluate(self, x, y, batch_size=32, verbose=1, sample_weight=None):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.pyc in _fit_loop(self, f, ins, out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_f, val_ins, shuffle, callback_metrics, initial_epoch)
   1150                 batch_logs['size'] = len(batch_ids)
   1151                 callbacks.on_batch_begin(batch_index, batch_logs)
-> 1152                 outs = f(ins_batch)
   1153                 if not isinstance(outs, list):
   1154                     outs = [outs]

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.pyc in __call__(self, inputs)
   2227         session = get_session()
   2228         updated = session.run(self.outputs + [self.updates_op],
-> 2229                               feed_dict=feed_dict)
   2230         return updated[:len(self.outputs)]
   2231

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    776     try:
    777       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 778                          run_metadata_ptr)
    779       if run_metadata:
    780         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    980     if final_fetches or final_targets:
    981       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
--> 982                              feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
    983     else:
    984       results = []

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1030     if handle is None:
   1031       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feed_dict, fetch_list,
-> 1032                            target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1033     else:
   1034       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feed_dict,

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1050         except KeyError:
   1051           pass
-> 1052       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1053
   1054   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [100,10] vs. [100]
         [[Node: gradients_4/add_121_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs = BroadcastGradientArgs[T=DT_INT32, _class=["loc:@add_121"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](gradients_4/add_121_grad/Shape, gradients_4/add_121_grad/Shape_1)]]

Caused by op u'gradients_4/add_121_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs', defined at:
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 119, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 355, in start
    self.shell.mainloop()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 493, in mainloop
    self.interact()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 484, in interact
    self.run_cell(code, store_history=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2718, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2828, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-5-475083cdc0be>", line 1, in <module>
    get_ipython().magic(u'run model2.py')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2160, in magic
    return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2081, in run_line_magic
    result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-58>", line 2, in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py", line 188, in <lambda>
    call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.py", line 742, in run
    run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.py", line 728, in run
    exit_ignore=exit_ignore)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2483, in safe_execfile
    self.compile if kw['shell_futures'] else None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.py", line 289, in execfile
    builtin_mod.execfile(filename, *where)
  File "/Users/yjluo/WORK/pitchPerfect/vae/model2.py", line 79, in <module>
    shuffle=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1481, in fit
    self._make_train_function()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1013, in _make_train_function
    self.total_loss)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 197, in get_updates
    grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 47, in get_gradients
    grads = K.gradients(loss, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2264, in gradients
    return tf.gradients(loss, variables, colocate_gradients_with_ops=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 560, in gradients
    grad_scope, op, func_call, lambda: grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 368, in _MaybeCompile
    return grad_fn()  # Exit early
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 560, in <lambda>
    grad_scope, op, func_call, lambda: grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_grad.py", line 598, in _AddGrad
    rx, ry = gen_array_ops._broadcast_gradient_args(sx, sy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 411, in _broadcast_gradient_args
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

...which was originally created as op u'add_121', defined at:
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
[elided 16 identical lines from previous traceback]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.py", line 289, in execfile
    builtin_mod.execfile(filename, *where)
  File "/Users/yjluo/WORK/pitchPerfect/vae/model2.py", line 68, in <module>
    vae.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss=vae_loss)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 910, in compile
    sample_weight, mask)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 436, in weighted
    score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/Users/yjluo/WORK/pitchPerfect/vae/model2.py", line 64, in vae_loss
    return(xent_loss + kl_loss)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 821, in binary_op_wrapper
    return func(x, y, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 73, in add
    result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Add", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [100,10] vs. [100]
         [[Node: gradients_4/add_121_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs = BroadcastGradientArgs[T=DT_INT32, _class=["loc:@add_121"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](gradients_4/add_121_grad/Shape, gradients_4/add_121_grad/Shape_1)]]
```

Based on the line `Incompatible shapes: [100,10] vs. [100]`, I believe it happens in loss computation but I can't figure out the solution. Moreover, even I don't do the slicing in `vae_loss()`, the error still show as `Incompatible shapes: [100,310] vs. [100]`. Could anyone please give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `xent_loss` is a 2D-tensor having a shape `(100, 10)`, and `kl_loss` is a 1D-tensor having a shape `(100)`. In tensorflow, it is invalid to add these two tensors. See [this section](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/broadcasting#broadcasting_a_lower-rank_array_onto_a_higher-rank_array) from the official doc.

> Consider the previous example, instead of adding a scalar to a (2,3) matrix, add a vector of dimension (3) to a matrix of dimensions (2,3). Without specifying broadcasting, this operation is invalid. To correctly request matrix-vector addition, specify the broadcasting dimension to be (1), meaning the vector's dimension is matched to dimension 1 of the matrix.

This occurs because `metrics.mean_squared_error()` takes an average over the feature axis, but not the time axis.

To fix this problem, either take another `K.mean()` over the time axis:

```
xent_loss = 10 * K.mean(metrics.mean_squared_error(x_, x_decoded_mean_), axis=-1)
```

or, use `K.squeeze()` to remove the features axes before feeding the tensors into `metrics.mean_squared_error()` (but this only applies to 1D time-series):

```
x_ = K.squeeze(x[:, 150:160, :], axis=-1)
x_decoded_mean_ = K.squeeze(x_decoded_mean[:, 150:160, :], axis=-1)
xent_loss = 10 * metrics.mean_squared_error(x_, x_decoded_mean_)
```

However, the best way is to forget about `metrics.mean_squared_error()`, and compute the MSE by yourself, with a correct `axis` argument.

```
xent_loss = 10 * K.mean(K.square(x_ - x_decoded_mean_), axis=[1, 2])
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarity! I should not be restricted by the Keras metrics!

Comment: I have the same problem but trying to adapt it to a 3D conv... what about this solution, does it make any sense? `xent_loss = original_dim * metrics.binary_crossentropy(K.flatten(x), K.flatten(x_decoded_mean))`