# Variational Autoencoder cross-entropy loss (xent_loss) with 3D convolutional layers

Tags: machine-learning, keras, autoencoder

I am adapting this implementation of VAE https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/variational_autoencoder.py that I found here https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html

This implementation does not use convolutional layers so everything happens in 1D so to speak. My goal is to implement 3D convolutional layers within this model.

However I run into a shape mismatch at the loss function when running the batches (which are of 128 samples):

```
def vae_loss(self, x, x_decoded_mean):
    xent_loss = original_dim * metrics.binary_crossentropy(x, x_decoded_mean)
    #xent_loss.shape >> [128, 40, 20, 40, 1]
    kl_loss = - 0.5 * K.sum(1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var), axis=-1)
    #kl_loss.shape >> [128]
    return K.mean(xent_loss + kl_loss) # >> error shape mismatch
```

Almost the same question is answered here already [Keras - Variational Autoencoder Incompatible shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45502673/keras-variational-autoencoder-incompatible-shape/45504584) for a model with 1D convolutional layers, but I can't really understand how to extrapolate the answer to my case wjich has a more complex Input shape.

I have tried this solution:

```
xent_loss = original_dim * metrics.binary_crossentropy(K.flatten(x), K.flatten(x_decoded_mean))
```

But I don't know whether it is a valid solution or not from a mathematical point of view, although now the model is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is right but it's highly dependent on `K.binary_crossentropy` implementation. `tensorflow` and `theano` ones should work for you (as far as I know). To make it more clean and not implementation dependent I suggest you the following way:

```
xent_loss_vec = original_dim * metrics.binary_crossentropy(x, x_decoded_mean)
xent_loss = K.mean(xent_loss_vec, axis=[1, 2, 3, 4])
# xent_loss.shape = (128,)
```

Now you are taking a mean out of losses for each voxel and thanks to that every valid implementation of `binary_crossentropy` should work fine for you.

Comment: It made a lot of sense when i read your answer but actually now its giving me this error at this line: `xent_loss = K.mean(xent_loss_vec, axis=[1, 2, 3, 4])` 
error >>
`ValueError: Invalid reduction dimension 4 for input with 4 dimensions. for 'custom_variational_layer_7/Mean_1' (op: 'Mean') with input shapes: [?,40,20,40], [4] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <1 2 3 4>`
It does work like this though: `xent_loss = K.mean(xent_loss_vec, axis=-1)` but then again, is it correct mathematically?

Comment: Weird. Try to set `axis=[1, 2, 3]`.